# Is it grammatically correct to use "Wake" without "up"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Is it possible to use "wake" as a standalone verb, without it being followed by the preposition "up"?

I heard the phrase,

*"I **woke** at 9:00 AM and felt strange"*,

but it quickly got corrected by someone else to,

*"I **woke up** at 9:00 AM and felt strange"*

Is the latter more correct than the former?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine in your example.

Adding 'up' can make it stronger and there are some cases where we always use 'wake up' (e.g. as a command: *Wake up! You have an interview this morning*).

Note these examples from the Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

*I always wake early in the summer.*

*They woke to a clear blue sky.*

*I was woken by the sound of someone moving around.*

(In all of the sentences above you can use 'up' as well.)

The Cambridge Dictionary gives the following example where 'up' is necessary:

*She likes to wake up with a cup of coffee. (It makes her feel more awake.)*