# Intransitive use of "to wake" vs. "to wake up"

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, differences, phrasal-verbs, semantics

> He woke in bed.

> He woke up in bed.

Is there a difference between the two? How does the lack/addition of "up" [affect the connotation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/418776/312114), if at all? Is one preferred over the other depending on the context?

Comment: I suspect you'll find that wake and wake up are used fairly interchangeably and mean the same thing. Awake, though rarely used in the vernacular now, is yet another variation of the same thing. Have you looked these up in any dictionaries? Have you looked at the etymologies?

Comment: I have, which is why I'm curious why there would be a variation.

Comment: You should include what research you've done here in your question.

Comment: For your first example, it would be more natural to say "He awoke in bed".

Comment: The question is not unnecessary. If you were to update it with evidence of the research you havedone it could be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wake%20at%2Cwoke%20at%2Cwake%20up%20at%2Cwoke%20up%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwake%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoke%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwake%20up%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoke%20up%20at%3B%2Cc0) shows their long co-existence, with the 'up' version currently more popular. Until the 20th century it was the other way round, which may be why - to my ears - "I woke at six" has a trace of formality.